# Can I connect to an SFTP server via HTTPS Proxy in Java?

Tags: java, https, proxy, jsch

I would like to connect to an SFTP server by tunneling over an HTTPS proxy. I see that [Java Proxies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Proxy.Type.html#HTTP), support three different types: Direct, HTTP, and Socks, but not HTTPS. Is there any way I can achieve this, or any third party libraries that might support this? Thanks!

I tried connecting via HTTP, but this did not work since the proxy I am connecting to only supports HTTPS connections